# No Credentials Provided for aws while using docker compose for a image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, open-telemetry

I am getting the below error of No Credentials Provided. I can see in the mount I have mounted the correct folder (Image attched). If I use a different image (amazon/aws-otel-collector:latest) the credentials work fine. But I want to use (otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:latest) image.

Failed to create stream token   {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "awscloudwatchlogs", "error": "NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\n\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors"}

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  otel:
    image:  otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:latest
    command: --config /config/collector-config-local.yml
    volumes:
      - $Userprofile/.aws:/root/.aws
      - .:/config
    environment:
      - AWS_REGION=ap-southeast-2
    ports:
      - '4317:4317'
```

**collector-config-local.yml**

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: info
  awscloudwatchlogs:
    log_group_name: "odessey/telemetry/test"
    log_stream_name: "teststream"
    region: ap-southeast-2
    endpoint: "logs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"                     
    sending_queue:
     queue_size: 10
    retry_on_failure:
     enabled: true
     initial_interval: 10ms
    
service:
  pipelines:
    logs:    
      receivers:
       - otlp
      exporters: 
       - awscloudwatchlogs
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright Had to add environment variable in the docker compose file. Below is the working approach.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  otel:
    image:  otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:latest
    command: --config /config/collector-config-local.yml
    volumes:
      - $Userprofile/.aws:/root/.aws
      - .:/config
    environment:
      - AWS_REGION=ap-southeast-2
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=MyKEY
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_MySecret
    ports:
      - '4317:4317'
```